# (SQL statement) Insert into 2 tables (and value needs to match)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, insert

First of all sorry for my bad english, english is not my native language.

So people need to type "Barcode" and "Classroom"
But Barcode doesn't need to be inserted. The "ComputerID" that matches the given barcode needs to be inserted in "TblLocation" (As well as "Classroom")

But you cant use WHERE or ON in a INSERT INTO statement?

---

(It's for a web application, I'm programming with ASP.net and VB in visual studio. And i'm ussing an ms sql database.)

[My 2 tables and form (example)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGFza.png)

Comment: Does Barcode have a unique index on it? If not, what do you want when there are more than 1 matches? What have you tried? This is a pretty straight forward join to get the value.

Comment: When a new classroom is given, the old one gets overwritten. So i guess i also need an UPDATE statement? But i also don't quite get the INSERT statement... Is it something like this?

INSERT INTO TblLocatie Classroom, ComputerID) VALUES (@ParameterClassroom,@ParameterComputerID) INNER JOIN TtblComputers ON TblComputers.ComputerID = TblLocatie.ComputerID;
Thanks.

Comment: From what you posted it is impossible to determine what your insert would be. What if there is no row for Barcode? What would you use? The biggest problem here is that you have not provided very much information. We don't know your project and can't see your screen. Let's start with the INSERT. What table(s) are needing to be inserted? Where do the values come from?

Comment: The only table where value needs to be added/Changed is in tblLocation.
people give the values "Barcode" and "classroom" but in tblLocation the value "ComputerID" needs to be added, so when you type the "Barcode" the application needs to see which "computerID" matches the barcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is still something totally missing from your explanation. From the form you posted if you need to update it would be something like this.

```
update l
set Classroom = @Classroom
from tblLocation l
join tblComputers c on c.ComputerID = l.ComputerID
where c.Barcode = @Barcode
```

Of course if there is no row in either table this won't update anything.

The other part is the INSERT. IF there is a row in tblComputers already you could do something like this.

```
insert tblLocation
(
    ComputerID
    , Classroom
)
select @Classroom
    , c.ComputerID
from tblComputers c
where c.Barcode = @Barcode
```

But what happens where there isn't a row in tblComputers? You would have to first create it right? There are so many holes in this still because you haven't provided any insight into your process. I hope the code I posted will at least get you started.

Comment: Their are 300 entries in TblComputers.
The program is about inventory.
So every computer has a location (Stands in a classroom)
The part where i'm stuck on is where they give in where the "Location" of the computer is. So they give the classroom en they scan or type the Barcode. But in TblComputers their is no "Barcode" only "ComputerID", So when people give the barcode the program needs to know wich ComputerID the barcode is from and needs to output the data (So "ComputerID" & "Classroom" in tblLocation)

Comment: HUH??? This doesn't make any sense. You are saying that the row in tblComputers does not have a value for Barcode, yet you want to find a related row in another table based on the value passed in...but there is no row with that value. I think you need to post the tables and some sample data along with some input parameters and the desired output. As you are describing this it just doesn't make sense.

Comment: Here are pictures from my database (This is from access because it's clearer.)
(Lokaal means Classroom)
http://imgur.com/a/Y8zbY

Comment: NO, sorry to confuse you, I have my database also in Access, so i took screenshots from my acces database, because i find that cleaner.

Comment: Gotcha. What would really be helpful is the ddl from sql server so I can run queries on my local instance. I just don't understand what you are trying to do but I am confident I can throw together your query in a few seconds once I know what it needs to do.

Comment: I could just send my Visual studio project (with database) to you if you want that? How can I send it to you?

Comment: Try this article. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Can't I just mail you my project? that would be a lot easier?

Comment: No that isn't how this works. I am not your personal free consultant. Besides others may have idea I don't. It really shouldn't take you more than about 10 minutes to script your tables and a dozen or so rows of sample data.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, it was already late in Belgium.
I understand what you mean, and I'm very grateful that you still take the time to help me. Here are the 2 tables you asked for.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d82d3

Comment: You fiddle is in mysql. I am really confused. You posted this in mysql, you also mentioned access but this is tagged as sql server. Which DBMS are you using??

Comment: I am using a MS SQL database, but i couldn't get MS SQL get to work on sqlfiddle.com

Comment: OK. Easy enough. Now...what part do you need help with? I provided the basic syntax for both insert and update. Is there some piece you need? What have you tried?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I think i almost got what I want;

INSERT INTO TblLocatie (Lokaal, ComputerID)
SELECT @ParameterLokaal, TblComputers.ComputerID
FROM TblComputers
WHERE TblComputers.Barcode = @ParameterBarcode;

But there's still something wrong...

Comment: I got it: INSERT INTO TblLocatie(ComputerID, Lokaal) SELECT ComputerID, @LokaalPara AS Expr1 FROM TblComputers WHERE (Barcode = @BarcodePara)

Comment: You are still using scalar variables in here which makes me concerned that you think these tables will only ever have 1 row but since we have never actually seen any code it is hard to say.

Comment: And sadly your answer is almost the same as I posted here. You should consider marking this as the answer.